# Post or Display select form data using two buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am using two buttons in one select form. one button for paypal and another button for bitpay.  i tried to post form data on another page using my JavaScript and php code. But its not working.

Here is the code -

```
//Pay with Bitpay
$('#lvlBtcPay').click(function(e){` `var amounts = 
$("#valRechargeSelect").val();
document.getElementById('PayBitpay1').value = amounts;  ` 
document.bitpayForm.submit();
});

//Pay with Paypal                   
$('#lvlRechargeBtnPay').click(function(e){                                
var amount = $("#valRechargeSelect").val(); 
document.getElementById('montoPaypal').value = 
amount;`document.paypalForm.submit()
});



//Form for bitpay payment                                               
<form action="/displaydata.php" method="post" name="bitpayForm">       
<input type="hidden" id="PayBitpay1"  name="Amount" value=""></form>   
//Form for paypal payment
<form action="/paypal.php" method="post" name="paypalForm">
<input type="hidden" id="montoPaypal" name="amount" value=""> </form>
//Here is the select options
<select id="valRechargeSelect" class="form-control" >
<option value="0">Selecciona un monto</option>
<option value="5">$5</option>
<option value="10">$10</option>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="lvlRechargeBtnPay">Pay With 
Paypal</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="lvlBtcPay" type="Submit" name="Submit" 
>Pay With BTC</button>


//Here is the PHP code to display or post data - 
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['#valRechargeSelect'])){ `$selected_val = $_POST['amount'];
echo "You have selected Amount :" .$selected_val;
}?>
```

Comment: Could you please give a little more detail--define "its not working"?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a snippet from your code. You can uncomment the submit code to submit the form.

In your PHP code, `$_POST['#valRechargeSelect']` `#valRechargeSelect` is not a valid posted key because the `select` with id `valRechargeSelect` does not exist in the `form`.

You can have `$_POST['amount']` in your `displaydata.php` and `paypal.php` files when you submit the form(s).

```js
//Pay with Bitpay
$('#lvlBtcPay').click(function(e){
    var amount = $("#valRechargeSelect").val();
    document.getElementById('PayBitpay1').value = amount;
    console.log(amount);
    console.log('Submit form to: ',document.bitpayForm.action)
    //Uncomment the line below to submit the form.
    //document.bitpayForm.submit();
});

//Pay with Paypal                   
$('#lvlRechargeBtnPay').click(function(e){                                
    var amount = $("#valRechargeSelect").val(); 
    document.getElementById('montoPaypal').value = amount;
    console.log('Submit form to: ',document.paypalForm.action)
    console.log(amount);
    //Uncomment the line below to submit the form.
    //document.paypalForm.submit()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                            
<form action="/displaydata.php" method="post" name="bitpayForm">       
  <input type="hidden" id="PayBitpay1"  name="amount" value="">
</form>   

<form action="/paypal.php" method="post" name="paypalForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="montoPaypal" name="amount" value="">
</form>

<select id="valRechargeSelect" class="form-control" >
  <option value="0">Selecciona un monto</option>
  <option value="5">$5</option>
  <option value="10">$10</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="lvlRechargeBtnPay">Pay With Paypal</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="lvlBtcPay">Pay With BTC</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer buddy but, i have also tested it with alert(); and console.log  but data not going to another page.

Comment: Thanks issue solved, buy using name="amount1" in isset post.